# Get template string from file and automatically bind data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing SmsService to send text message to user's phone. The SmsService receives the text message content from `SmsContent`:

```
class SmsContent
  def initialize(sms_type, data)
    @sms_type = sms_type
    @data = data
  end

  def get_content
    sms_template_one_way = 'Hello #{customer_name}, this is your one way itinerary from #{depart_place} to #{arrive_place} ...'
    sms_template_round_trip = 'Hello #{customer_name}, this is your round trip itinerary from #{depart_place} to #{arrive_place} ...'

    customer_name = @data.customer_name
    depart_place = @data.depart_place
    arrive_place = @data.arrive_place

    if @sms_type == 1
      sms_content = sms_template_round_trip
    else
      sms_content = sms_template_one_way
    end

    sms_content
  end
end
```

I have to store my message template as `String` variables. How can I refactor this code? Specifically, how can I store message templates in a file and automatically bind data to template?

Comment: just use `render` method.

Comment: I'm a new Ruby guy, so it will be nice if you give an example link for render this

Comment: Note that your template as they are now will be able to execute arbitrary ruby code. As such, you should never accept these from a user or else a user can execute arbitrary code in your app (which ould steal passwords, change data, ...). If you want to accept these templates fom a user you should use a safe template language like [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) instead.

Comment: Why not use Rails' I18n API, which is basically designed for this exact thing? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation

Comment: @HolgerJust I don't see the vulnerability. Give me a hint?

Comment: @Jordan The "templates" in the question are basically ruby code which look like they are `eval`ed by the caller somehow (not shown here). These "templates" as well as e.g ERB template can thus execute arbitrary ruby code. If the templates are provided by the user, you have a remote-code-execution vulnerability.

Comment: It doesn't look like the templates are user-supplied, but you're right that if `eval` is used this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SmsContent
  def initialize(sms_type, data); @sms_type, @data = sms_type, data end
  def get_content
    "Hello %{customer_name}, this is your %{sms_type} itinerary "\
    "from %{depart_place} to %{arrive_place} ..." %
    {
      sms_type:      @sms_type == 1 ? "round trip" : "one way",
      customer_name: @data.customer_name,
      depart_place:  @data.depart_place,
      arrive_place:  @data.arrive_place,
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a partial file under app/views/sms_content/_get_content.html.erb

**_get_content.html.erb**

```
<% if @sms_type == 1 %>
    Hello <%= @data.customer_name %>, this is your one way itinerary from <%= @data.depart_place %> to <%= @data.arrive_place %> ...
<% else %>
    Hello <%= @data.customer_name %>, this is your round trip itinerary from <%= @data.depart_place %> to <%= @data.arrive_place %> ...
<% end %>
```

In your `SmsContent` class `get_content` method

```
def get_content
   render :partial => "sms_content/get_content"
end
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

As I indicated in my comment above, Rails' built-in [I18n API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) is practically designed for this exact thing. First, store your template strings in the `config/locales/` directory:

```yaml
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  sms_template:
    one_way:
      Hello %{customer_name}, this is your one way itinerary
      from %{depart_place} to %{arrive_place} ...
    round_trip:
      Hello %{customer_name}, this is your round trip itinerary
      from %{depart_place} to %{arrive_place} ...
```

Note that this format uses `%{...}` *a la* `sprintf` for interpolation instead of `#{...}`.

Then:

```
def get_content
  template_name = @sms_type == 1 ? "round_trip" : "one_way"
  I18n.t("sms_template.#{template_name}", @data.attributes)
end
```

That's it! One thing to note: The above assumes that `@data` is an ActiveModel object (or something that responds to `attributes` with a Hash); if that's not the case you'll have to build a Hash first.